# How to pass object to overrideParameters for ARM deployment from yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yaml pipeline that executes an inline script and needs to pass the output object from that script to an ARM template but I cannot find any examples around which pass an object, only individual strings.

The yaml script:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
    displayName: 'Get CosmosDB Consistency'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'ado-test'
      scriptType: 'inlineScript'
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
      inline: | 
        Install-Module -Name Az.CosmosDB -RequiredVersion 0.1.6 -AllowClobber -Force
        Import-Module Az.CosmosDB
        $cosmosConsistency = (Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $(domain)-${{ parameters.environment }} -Name $(domain)-${{ parameters.environment }}).ConsistencyPolicy
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=cosmosConsistency;isOutput=true]$cosmosConsistency"
      name: 'cosmosConsistency'
```

The output object looks like this: `{"DefaultConsistencyLevel":"Session","MaxStalenessPrefix":100,"MaxIntervalInSeconds":5}`

The ARM deployment with param override:

```
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
    displayName: 'Deploy: Main resources'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'ado-test'
      resourceGroupName: '$(domain)-${{ lower(parameters.environment) }}'
      location: 'West Europe'
      csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/resources.json'
      csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/resources.parameters.json'
      overrideParameters: '-cosmosConsistency $(cosmosConsistency))'
```

Param definition in ARM template:

```
cosmosConsistency": {
      "type": "object",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Cosmos DB consistency parameters object"
      }
    },
```

The error I am getting is that param is string but object was expected so there is either something wrong with my overrideParameters definition or the param definition in the ARM template.

Can someone pls assist with the correct syntax?

If I pass all 3 values separately as 3 different string params it works but is messy and I rather pass the whole object instead.

Comment: Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you? If yes, you can accept the answer which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Answer (score 1):

To override object type parameters use stringified JSON objects.
For example, -options ["option1"] -map {"key1":"value1" }.

If there is a gap between "key1" and "value1" like "key": "value1", it will give an error "mapping values are not allowed in this context". So correct syntax would be {"key1":"value1"}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops